# Bash Script : Handling Arguments

Tags: bash, shell, arguments

Can a bash/shell guru help me make a really simple bash script which handles the following - im struggling to get it working along these lines

Input is as following

```
./script #channel1,#channel2,#channel3 "This is the message"
```

or if easier..

```
./script #channel1,#channel2,#channel3 -m This is the message
```

(anything after the -m  is the message)

Now I want to loop through each of the channels, and echo the message, ie

```
for channel in channels
    echo channel $message
fi
```

thanks

Comment: Did you actually have your `channel` argument starting with a `#`?  If so, that was probably the heart of the problem.  `#` tells bash that everything from there to the end of the line is a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing it, it would be easier to do

```sh
usage ()
{
  echo "usage: $0 <MESSAGE> <CHANNELS>"
  exit
}

[[ $3 ]] || usage
message=$1
shift

for channel
do
  echo $channel $message
done
```

Comment: hi thanks for feedback, but i cant get it to work... anything i type just comes up with  usage <message> <channels>  ...?

Comment: ./script "This is a message" channel1,channel2   comes up with 'usage blah' ...?

Comment: @TylerEvans: don't include commas in your channel list. Recall that $3 means the third argument, and in your sample, you only have two arguments (because the shell separates on quoted strings, and then white space (not commas) ). Good luck to all.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[[ $2 ]] || usage` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
channels=$1
message=$2
IFS=,
for channel in $channels
do  echo $channel $message
done
```

Example:

```
0>./script channel1,channel2,channel3 "This is the message"
channel1 This is the message
channel2 This is the message
channel3 This is the message
```